# Differentiable irreducible representations of the abelian group $(\mathbb{R}^d,+)$

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

In Woit's book chapter 20, he considers character of the group $(\mathbb{R}^d,+)$. Now he claims that irreducible representations of $(\mathbb{R}^d,+)$ are one dimensional and given by $\alpha_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{a}) = e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{a}} $.
For $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and $\mathbf{p}$ is in another  copy of $\mathbb{R}^d$ . Think of it as position and momentum.

I can't justify this claim myself.
I know that any irreducible of Abelian group is $1$-dimensional, so the irreps can be characterized by group characters as used above. But why is it of that form? I was thinking of using Pontryagin duality to get that form like in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not entirely sure as I have limited background in Harmonic Analysis.

Comment: By considering the subgroup of elements in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with only  one nonzero coordinate it suffices to show that the characters are of the form $e^{ix_kp_k}$ where $k$ denotes that coordinate. Then study the behavior of this character for rational values of $x_k.$